# How to force Visual studio C++ compiler to inline a procedure defined in a separate external file?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, inline, inline-assembly

Suppose that I have an external `.asm` file that contain below procedure definition:

```
PSRAX   PROC
    push rax
    ret
PSRAX   ENDP
```

And I used that procedure with `extern "C" int PSRAX();`, however I want codes to be inlined, so I looked into the machine codes and figured that it is using `call` instruction to execute the procedure. How I can force compiler inline those assembly codes in C++? I am using latest version of VS.

I tried `__forceinline int PSRAX();`, but does not work. Also it is x64 so I cant use `__asm`.

Comment: Define it as a macro instead of a function.

Comment: What's the point of the exercise? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? The shown assembly seems to mean "jump to whatever address happens to be in `RAX` at the moment", which sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: The [Microsoft Assembler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/ml-and-ml64-command-line-reference?view=msvc-170) does not have an option for [link-time-code-generation / whole-program-optimisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gl-whole-program-optimization?view=msvc-170)

Comment: This is impossible. Compiler can not inline external function, about which he no enough knowledge. Simply point - for inline need remove ret instructions. But compiler dont know how many and where ret located

Comment: @RbMm I removed `ret` from my proc and used `__forceinline` and still the compiler uses `call` instruction, I am even fine with being able to inline proc without ret.

Comment: If you implement the function in C using inline assembly and place the definition in a header file, the compiler could inline it. However, if the code do strange things to the stack, it might not work as expected.

Comment: C++ compilers can't inline hand-written asm functions.   Use inline assembly if you want that.  (Which means using a compiler other than MSVC if you're targeting anything except 32-bit x86.)  A compiler has to assume that functions it doesn't have C++ source for only exist in machine code that's designed to be called according to the standard calling convention.  There's no standard way of transforming them, so nobody's added support for compilers to read asm source files or `.obj` files.

Comment: If you just want to tailcall a pointer, write that in pure C++, like `int (*fptr)() = something;`  then `return fptr();`.

Comment: @Lindydancer no, not you must remove ret from fuction, but compiler. And it can not, because not have any information about it. Inlined function code, different from function code. Only in case compiler by self generate code for function, can do such transformation